# Cannot access protected variables that i have declared in code behind from ASPX Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please can anyone suggest why I cannot access code behind protected variables with my ASPX page as below

//Code Behind//

[image]

//ReadInMessage.ASPX Page//

[image]

Comment: What do you mean can't access?  What happens?

Also if you have `<%= %>` you don't need `Response.Write()`.  Try just `<%=messageId%>`.

Comment: Still the variable doesn't show up in the ASPX page

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra, try re-building your application. Remove the reference from ASPX and re build you application. Try then

Comment: Are you sure that `messageId` actually has content?

If it were an accessibility issue, the page would fail to compile properly.

Comment: yes, page fails to compile and it says "The name messageid doesnot exist in current context

Comment: Oh, ok then.  Does the `Page` directive in your ASPX document have `Inherits="ReadInMessage"`?  Additionally, do you have any outstanding compiler errors?

Comment: I guess the rebuild worked!! Wheww!!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - because, you can't.

You can use `Session` variable itself to send the data to `aspx`

```
<%= Response.Write(Convert.ToString(Session["messageID"]))%>
```

Comment: Please can you tell me how

Comment: Yes, you can.  The page is inherited from the code-behind class so it has access to all the public and protected members.

Answer (score 0):

After rebuilding the solution, The code behind variables could be accessed through the ASPX page, Thank You All for the support